# Why do I keep getting Import error in skimage python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, jupyter-notebook, scikit-image

I am fed up with this message..tried google/stackoverflow search..

Applied found fixes(like upgrading versions etc..)

Nothing works and I keep getting..
(for example while using->

```
from skimage.morphology import erosion, dilation, opening, closing, white_tophat
```

)

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-92efc73cf055> in <module>
      4 import cv2
      5 import os
----> 6 from skimage.morphology import erosion, dilation, opening, closing, white_tophat
      7 from skimage.morphology import black_tophat, skeletonize, convex_hull_image
      8 from skimage.morphology import disk

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\skimage\__init__.py in <module>
    174                              dtype_limits)
    175 
--> 176     from .util.lookfor import lookfor
    177     from .data import data_dir
    178 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\__init__.py in <module>
      6 from .apply_parallel import apply_parallel
      7 
----> 8 from .arraycrop import crop
      9 from ._regular_grid import regular_grid, regular_seeds
     10 from .unique import unique_rows

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\arraycrop.py in <module>
      6 
      7 import numpy as np
----> 8 from numpy.lib.arraypad import _validate_lengths
      9 
     10 

ImportError: cannot import name '_validate_lengths' from 'numpy.lib.arraypad' (C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraypad.py)
```

Appreciate any help to fix this,Thanks.

Comment: Can you give your versions of Python, numpy, and scikit-image?

Comment: btw how can i programatically view the version of scikit-image? like `scipy.__version__` is there any method? @Eskapp

Comment: In a terminal, if you use a conda environment, you should be able to do `conda list` to get the list of the installed packages.

Comment: numpy- 1.16.0  python-3.7  skimage-0.15 @Eskapp

Comment: You can downgrade NumPy, or make sure that you are actually running skimage 0.15.  Version 0.14.1 was incompatible with the latest version of NumPy, but that was fixed in 0.14.2.

Comment: yes..I have found that issue listed on github thats why I upgraded the skimage version accordingly to 0.15